# Applet Being Selective on Which AudioClips it will Play and Not Play

Tags: java, audio, applet, clip

I am currently working on a soundboard for my Java class and my GUI isn't working.  I have uploaded all of my resource sound clips in .wav format to a resource folder in Eclipse, with all of the proper arguments and instances.  Most of the AudioClips work when I click on them in the GUI, but some just simply won't play.  Here is the code:

```
audHomer = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Homer.wav");
audMarge = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Marge.wav");
audBart = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Bart.wav");
audLisa = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Lisa.wav");
audMaggie = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Maggie.wav");
audMilhouse = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Milhouse.wav");
audMoe = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "Moe.wav");
audMrBurns = getAudioClip(getDocumentBase(), "MrBurns.wav");
```

And here is where they are used with the individual buttons:

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object clicked = e.getSource();
        if(clicked == btnHomer)
        {
            lblOutput.setIcon(imgHomer);
            audHomer.play();
        }
        if(clicked == btnMarge)
        {
            lblOutput.setIcon(imgMarge);
            audMarge.play(); //Will not play
        }
        if(clicked == btnBart)
        {
            lblOutput.setIcon(imgBart);
            audBart.play();
        }
        if(clicked == btnLisa)
        {
            lblOutput.setIcon(imgLisa);
            audLisa.play(); //Will not play
        }
        if(clicked == btnMaggie)
        {
            lblOutput.setIcon(imgMaggie);
            audMaggie.play();
        }
        if(clicked == btnMilhouse)
        {
            lblOutput.setIcon(imgMilhouse);
            audMilhouse.play();
        }
        if(clicked == btnMoe)
        {
            lblOutput.setIcon(imgMoe);
            audMoe.play(); //Will not play
        }
        if(clicked == btnMrBurns)
        {
            lblOutput.setIcon(imgMrBurns);
            audMrBurns.play();
        }
    }
}
```

I have all of the files named exactly what they are labeled as in the code above but they just aren't working.  I thought that the size of the files might have been an issue, but it seems that some of the files that are playing are twice the size of those that aren't.

Comment: What internal encoding do the WAVs use?  My guess is that the 'bigger' ones that play use a simpler format, while the ones that don't are encoded as MP3 internally. BTW - for better control and more reporting, use the Java Sound based `Clip` to play them.

Comment: They all use Cp1252 and thanks for the tip, I was just using the object our instructor gave us, but in the future I'll probably use that instead.

Comment: *"I was just using the object our instructor gave us"*  So a teacher is forcing you to code applets?  Please refer them to [Why CS teachers should *stop* teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  *"They all use Cp1252"*  Wait, *what*?!?  You do realize that [CP-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) relates only to text, right?  It has nothing to do with the encoding of the sound itself!